# How to put a long character string into an array?

Tags: arrays, string

So I have to take a long quote and turn it into an array. I know how to do it with small strings but if I have a really long quote that I can't count I'm not sure how to approach that.  If I do:

```
char prose[] = "Two things fill the mind with ever new and increasing admiration and awe,       the more often and steadily we reflect upon them: the starry heavens above me and the moral    law within me. I do not seek or conjecture either of them as if they were veiled obscurities or extravagances beyond the horizon of my vision; I see them before me and connect them    immediately with the consciousness of my existence.”;
```

My compiler goes crazy with errors. This obviously longer than like a 10 line string.

Comment: Please specify your exact problem along with the language used!!

Comment: You have a curly quote at the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Thats's because you are using wrong quotes for the string.

Using `".."` works fine, your end quote doesn't match your start quote symbol.

Comment: @user3435810: Glad could help, you can accept the ans.